# EXPLAIN в mysql

Tags: explain, оптимизация, sql

Пытаюсь оптимизировать запрос через EXPLAIN. Получил следующее:

[image]

Что и как тут?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html ?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, ага

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Показал возможные ключи, а используется только один.

Значит надо посмотреть на структуру и возможно добавить нужные ключи (что не всегда требуется, т.к. ключи ускоряют выборку, но тормозят вставку/обновление).

Либо пересмотреть запрос - возможно стоит оптимизировать его, а не БД.

Без самого запроса и структуры таблицы трудно сказать что и как.

Таблицу по одному из вопросов помню, но я уже советовал - переставить индексы, поэтому возможно она (структура) поменялась.

Так что ничего конкретного пока сказать нельзя.

Comment: Че-то ни фига не понял...

Вроде писал комментарий, а получился ответ...

Либо чудеса, либо на пенсию уже пора....

Comment: @BOPOH видимо, ваш комментарий был на самом деле ответом, добрые люди его преобразовали в ответ, бывает. Тем более что ответ по делу и принят.